# Is it possible to detect which script is responsible for a DOM modification?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

Currently in my chrome extensions I am blocking requests to domains that are on my block list. I would like to let them through and detect when code from those domains create dom elements.

I know how to detect DOM modifications using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but I still am unable to figure out which script from which domain triggered it.

Who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: if you can inject a script before any others you can weave `document.createElement` to give you a stack trace while maintaining the script's original functionality

Comment: Try to check this [article](http://elijahmanor.com/7-chrome-tips-developers-designers-may-not-know/) if it can help you. This article has a guide on how to break JavaScript when an element has changed in the DOM. The chrome does it by the following unique features like Break on subtree modifications, Break on attributes modifications and Break on node removal. Just check the link for the screenshot.